# Flex Mobile View Component Access Main Application

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, adobe, flex4.6

Is there a way within Flex Mobile 4.6 to access the main application from within a `<s:View>` component? Let's say my program looks like this:

Main application:

```
<s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                  creationComplete="databaseConnection(event)">

  <s:ViewNavigator id="tasks" width="100%" height="100%"
                       label="Tasks" firstView="views.TasksView"
                       title="Tasks" icon="@Embed('assets/icons/tasks.png')">
  </s:ViewNavigator>
</s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication>
```

view.TasksView:

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

  <s:List left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"
     dataProvider="{taskData}" itemRenderer="renderers.TaskListRenderer"/>
</s:View>
```

Let's say that there is a variable within the main application that I would like to access within `view.TasksView`. How can I do that?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FlexGlobals](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/FlexGlobals.html).[topLevelApplication](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/FlexGlobals.html#topLevelApplication)

In your case:

```
var app : TabbedViewNavigatorApplication = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as TabbedViewNavigatorApplication
```

Of course, accessing the top level application is a great break in encapsulation and not usually recommended.

Comment: You're right. It is quite a break in the idea behind encapsulation, but it will work in this case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use "parentApplication" property.
For example if you want to disable tab button of view "vsetting" from other views:

```
parentApplication.vsetting.enabled = false;
```